# Knapsack with SPECIFIC AMOUNT of items from different groups

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

So this is a variation of the Knapsack Problem I came with the other day.

It is like a [0-1 Knapsack Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/) where there are multiple groups and each item belongs to only one group. The goal is to maximize the profits subject to the constraints. In this case, a fixed number of items from each group have to be chosen for each group.

It is similar to the Multiple Choice Knapsack Problem, but in that case you only pick 1 of item of each group, in this one you want to pick `x` amount of items of each group

So, each item has: value, weight and group

Each group has an item count (Ex: if group A (or 0) has 2, the final solution needs to have 2 items of group A, no more no less)

And and you also have a maximum capacity (not related to the groups)

This translates into:

- `values[i]` = The value of the ith element
- `weights[i]` = The weigth of the ith element
- `groups[i]` = The group of the ith element
- `C` = Capacity
- `n` = Amount of elements
- `m` = Amount of groups
- `count[j]` = Amount of items of group j

I'm attempting a Recursive solution first and then I will try a Dynamic approach.

Any solution would be appreciated (preferably Python, but anything will do :) ).

Usefull links I found:

- [Theorical solution of a similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375851/multiple-choice-knapsack-problem-mckp-where-one-class-requires-more-than-one-i)
- [First approach to the Multiple Choice Knapsack Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684018/forming-dynamic-programming-algorithm-for-a-variation-of-knapsack-problem)
- [Multiple Choice Knapsack Problem solved in Python](https://gist.github.com/USM-F/1287f512de4ffb2fb852e98be1ac271d)
- [Knapsack with count constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891999/knapsack-multiple-constraints)

Comment: You can convert the problem to multiple choice knapsack by preprocessing the groups. For example, consider a group with 4 items whose `(weight, value)` are `[(3,10), (3,11), (4,12), (5,13)]`, and the count for the group is 2. Then there are six possible `(weight, value)` pairs that use 2 items: `[(6,21), (7,22), (8,23), (7,23), (8,24), (9,25)]`. Notice that some of the weights appear twice, with different values. The pair with the lower value can be discarded. Which makes the preprocessing step similar to the subset sum problem: you seek the best value for each possible subset sum.

Comment: @user3386109 you are completely right, I didn't think about it! I think it will be a bit harder to figure what combination gave the final result, but it should work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Full code also in: https://github.com/pabloroldan98/knapsack-football-formations**

**Explanation after the code.**

This code is for an example where you have a Fantasy League with a `playersDB` where each player has price (weight), points (value) and position (group); there is a list of `possible_formations` (group variations); and a `budget` (W) you can't go over.

### Full code:

- main.py:

  ```
    from group_knapsack import best_full_teams

    playersDB = [
        Player(name="Keylor Navas", price=16, points=7.5, position="GK"),
        Player(name="Laporte", price=23, points=7.2, position="DEF"),
        Player(name="Modric", price=22, points=7.3, position="MID"),
        Player(name="Messi", price=51, points=8.2, position="ATT"),
        ...
    ]

    possible_formations = [
        [3, 4, 3],
        [3, 5, 2],
        [4, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 2],
        [4, 5, 1],
        [5, 3, 2],
        [5, 4, 1],
    ]

    budget = 300


    best_full_teams(playersDB, possible_formations, budget)
  ```
- group_knapsack.py:

  ```
    import itertools

    from MCKP import knapsack_multichoice_onepick


    def best_full_teams(players_list, formations, budget):
        formation_score_players = []

        for formation in formations:
            players_points, players_prices, players_comb_indexes = players_preproc(
                players_list, formation)

            score, comb_result_indexes = knapsack_multichoice_onepick(
                players_prices, players_points, budget)

            result_indexes = []
            for comb_index in comb_result_indexes:
                for winning_i in players_comb_indexes[comb_index[0]][comb_index[1]]:
                    result_indexes.append(winning_i)

            result_players = []
            for res_index in result_indexes:
                result_players.append(players_list[res_index])

            formation_score_players.append((formation, score, result_players))

            print("With formation " + str(formation) + ": " + str(score))
            for best_player in result_players:
                print(best_player)
            print()
            print()

        formation_score_players_by_score = sorted(formation_score_players,
                                                  key=lambda tup: tup[1],
                                                  reverse=True)
        for final_formation_score in formation_score_players_by_score:
            print((final_formation_score[0], final_formation_score[1]))

        return formation_score_players


    def players_preproc(players_list, formation):
        max_gk = 1
        max_def = formation[0]
        max_mid = formation[1]
        max_att = formation[2]

        gk_values, gk_weights, gk_indexes = generate_group(players_list, "GK")
        gk_comb_values, gk_comb_weights, gk_comb_indexes = group_preproc(gk_values,
                                                                         gk_weights,
                                                                         gk_indexes,
                                                                         max_gk)

        def_values, def_weights, def_indexes = generate_group(players_list, "DEF")
        def_comb_values, def_comb_weights, def_comb_indexes = group_preproc(
            def_values, def_weights, def_indexes, max_def)

        mid_values, mid_weights, mid_indexes = generate_group(players_list, "MID")
        mid_comb_values, mid_comb_weights, mid_comb_indexes = group_preproc(
            mid_values, mid_weights, mid_indexes, max_mid)

        att_values, att_weights, att_indexes = generate_group(players_list, "ATT")
        att_comb_values, att_comb_weights, att_comb_indexes = group_preproc(
            att_values, att_weights, att_indexes, max_att)

        result_comb_values = [gk_comb_values, def_comb_values, mid_comb_values,
                              att_comb_values]
        result_comb_weights = [gk_comb_weights, def_comb_weights, mid_comb_weights,
                               att_comb_weights]
        result_comb_indexes = [gk_comb_indexes, def_comb_indexes, mid_comb_indexes,
                               att_comb_indexes]

        return result_comb_values, result_comb_weights, result_comb_indexes


    def generate_group(full_list, group):
        group_values = []
        group_weights = []
        group_indexes = []
        for i, item in enumerate(full_list):
            if item.position == group:
                group_values.append(item.points)
                group_weights.append(item.price)
                group_indexes.append(i)
        return group_values, group_weights, group_indexes


    def group_preproc(group_values, group_weights, initial_indexes, r):
        comb_values = list(itertools.combinations(group_values, r))
        comb_weights = list(itertools.combinations(group_weights, r))
        comb_indexes = list(itertools.combinations(initial_indexes, r))

        group_comb_values = []
        for value_combinations in comb_values:
            values_added = sum(list(value_combinations))
            group_comb_values.append(values_added)

        group_comb_weights = []
        for weight_combinations in comb_weights:
            weights_added = sum(list(weight_combinations))
            group_comb_weights.append(weights_added)

        return group_comb_values, group_comb_weights, comb_indexes
  ```
- MCKP.py:

  ```
    import copy


    def knapsack_multichoice_onepick(weights, values, max_weight):
        if len(weights) == 0:
            return 0

        last_array = [-1 for _ in range(max_weight + 1)]
        last_path = [[] for _ in range(max_weight + 1)]
        for i in range(len(weights[0])):
            if weights[0][i] < max_weight:
                if last_array[weights[0][i]] < values[0][i]:
                    last_array[weights[0][i]] = values[0][i]
                    last_path[weights[0][i]] = [(0, i)]

        for i in range(1, len(weights)):
            current_array = [-1 for _ in range(max_weight + 1)]
            current_path = [[] for _ in range(max_weight + 1)]
            for j in range(len(weights[i])):
                for k in range(weights[i][j], max_weight + 1):
                    if last_array[k - weights[i][j]] > 0:
                        if current_array[k] < last_array[k - weights[i][j]] + \
                                values[i][j]:
                            current_array[k] = last_array[k - weights[i][j]] + \
                                               values[i][j]
                            current_path[k] = copy.deepcopy(
                                last_path[k - weights[i][j]])
                            current_path[k].append((i, j))
            last_array = current_array
            last_path = current_path

        solution, index_path = get_onepick_solution(last_array, last_path)

        return solution, index_path


    def get_onepick_solution(scores, paths):
        scores_paths = list(zip(scores, paths))
        scores_paths_by_score = sorted(scores_paths, key=lambda tup: tup[0],
                                       reverse=True)

        return scores_paths_by_score[0][0], scores_paths_by_score[0][1]
  ```
- player.py:

  ```
    class Player:
        def __init__(
                self,
                name: str,
                price: float,
                points: float,
                position: str
        ):
            self.name = name
            self.price = price
            self.points = points
            self.position = position

        def __str__(self):
            return f"({self.name}, {self.price}, {self.points}, {self.position})"

        @property
        def position(self):
            return self._position

        @position.setter
        def position(self, pos):
            if pos not in ["GK", "DEF", "MID", "ATT"]:
                raise ValueError("Sorry, that's not a valid position")
            self._position = pos

        def get_group(self):
            if self.position == "GK":
                group = 0
            elif self.position == "DEF":
                group = 1
            elif self.position == "MID":
                group = 2
            else:
                group = 3
            return group
  ```

### Explanation:

Okay,so I managed to find a solution translating what was here: [Solving the Multiple Choice Knapsack Problem](https://nickgavalas.com/solving-the-multiple-choice-knapsack-problem/) from `C++` to `Python`. My solution also gives the path that got you to that solution. It uses Dynamic Programming and it's very fast.

The input data, instead of having `groups[i]`, has the weights and the values  as a list of lists, where every list inside represent the values of each group:

- `weights[i] = [weights_group_0, weights_group_1, ...]`
- `values[i] = [values_group_0, values_group_1, ...]`

Where:

- `weights_group_i[j]` = The weigth of the `j`th element of the `i`th group
- `values_group_i[j]` = The value of the `j`th element of the `i`th group

Those would be the inputs of `knapsack_multichoice_onepick`. Here is an example:

```
# Example
values = [[6, 10], [12, 2], [2, 3]]
weights = [[1, 2], [6, 2], [3, 2]]
W = 7

print(knapsack_multichoice_onepick(weights, values, W))  # (15, [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)])
```

After that I followed @user3386109 's suggestion and did the combinations with the indexes. The group preprocesing methods are `players_preproc`, `generate_group` and `group_preproc`.

Again, this code is for an example where you have a Fantasy League with a `playersDB` where each player has price (weight), points (value) and position (group); there is a list of `possible_formations` (group variations); and a `budget` (W) you can't go over.

The `best_full_teams` method prints everything and uses all the previous ones.